# Insert new record into table based off highest value in another table with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I have two tables:

table_1:

> | id | name |

table_2

> | id | table_1_id |

table_1 has many rows and I would like to select the highest id value from table_1 & insert it as a new record into table_2 in the table_1 column.

Is there someone who could help me with the mysql for this as I have been unable to achieve it? From what I have read I would need to join the columns but I have been unable to find the correct syntax.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don't need to join anything, you just need to select the max id and then insert it. Nothing complicated.

Comment: Yes. See the manual under INSERT

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, table_1_id) VALUES (null, (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_1 ))
```

EDIT: I am assuming that id in table2 is auto_increment or has other meaningful default value. Another option would simply omit the id column in the insert however IMO that is bad for code readability.

Comment: You are inserting a null value in table2.id, that not seems right.

Comment: @RubioRic If you insert NULL into a non-nullable column, it assumes the default value for that column

Comment: @Strawberry It depends on how the column was defined, doesn't it? I'm no MySQL expert but is a default value established for each column if you don't specify one? What happens when you insert your second row with id=null?

Comment: @RubioRic All non-null columns are *supposed* to be defined with a default value. You're right that it's not automatic, but it's unusual for an id column not to be autoincrementing - in which case the default value is of course automatically defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assign both table id is primary & auto increment 

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_1 (name) VALUES ('kane')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     /// Table1 value insert successfully
     $last_insert_id = $conn->insert_id;

     $sql1 = "INSERT INTO table_2 (table_1_id) VALUES ($last_insert_id)";
     if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      /// Table2 value insert successfully
     }


    }
```

Comment: You need to wrap this with a transaction otherwise you may get concurrency problems https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table_2 
SELECT <new_id_value> id,  MAX(id) table_1_id FROM table_1;
```